# Gmail Confirm actions (and roll-out schedule)

Tags: google-schemas

I'm testing actions with the Apps Script tutorial (with emails sent to myself), but currently only Go-To actions show up. This is the code I use to generate a Confirm Action, am I doing something wrong?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "description": "Retry fax sending",
    "action": {
        "@type": "ConfirmAction",
        "name": "Retry",
        "handler": {
            "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
            "url": "http://example.com/do/ba98262b-6eb9-4314-a01a-8ff3076821e3"
            "method": "POST"
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, is there any place in which we can check the status of roll-out of Gmail Actions? For instance, my Google Apps account does not show any action, while my "standard" Gmail account does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply missing a comma after the `handler.url` property, this is the correct markup:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "description": "Retry fax sending",
    "action": {
        "@type": "ConfirmAction",
        "name": "Retry",
        "handler": {
            "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
            "url": "http://example.com/do/ba98262b-6eb9-4314-a01a-8ff3076821e3",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You can use the Schema Validator tool to check your markup for syntax errors like this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema

Go-To and One-Click actions are launched, while Review and RSVP are not yet. Please track the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/release-notes) page to get all updates.

For what concerns Google Apps accounts, please note that domain admins decide which track they want to be part of and that controls when they get the new features.